# python pandas filter dataframe by another series, multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

After getting a series of days with the highest delivery numbers, how can I filter out the original dataframe for just those days? Given these two:

```
most_liquid_contracts.head(20)
Out[32]: 
2007-04-26    706
2007-04-27    706
2007-04-29    706
2007-04-30    706
2007-05-01    706
2007-05-02    706
2007-05-03    706
2007-05-04    706
2007-05-06    706
2007-05-07    706
2007-05-08    706
2007-05-09    706
2007-05-10    706
2007-05-11    706
2007-05-13    706
2007-05-14    706
2007-05-15    706
2007-05-16    706
2007-05-17    706
2007-05-18    706
dtype: int64

df.head(20).to_string
Out[40]: 
<bound method DataFrame.to_string of                            
                              delivery  volume
2007-04-27 11:55:00+01:00       705       1
2007-04-27 13:46:00+01:00       705       1
2007-04-27 14:15:00+01:00       705       1
2007-04-27 14:33:00+01:00       705       1
2007-04-27 14:35:00+01:00       705       1
2007-04-27 17:05:00+01:00       705      16
2007-04-27 17:07:00+01:00       705       1
2007-04-27 17:12:00+01:00       705       1
2007-04-27 17:46:00+01:00       705       1
2007-04-27 18:25:00+01:00       705       2
2007-04-26 23:00:00+01:00       706      10
2007-04-26 23:01:00+01:00       706      12
2007-04-26 23:02:00+01:00       706       1
2007-04-26 23:05:00+01:00       706      21
2007-04-26 23:06:00+01:00       706      10
2007-04-26 23:07:00+01:00       706      19
2007-04-26 23:08:00+01:00       706       1
2007-04-26 23:13:00+01:00       706      10
2007-04-26 23:14:00+01:00       706      62
2007-04-26 23:15:00+01:00       706       3>
```

I've tried:

```
liquid = df[df.index.date==most_liquid_contracts.index & df['delivery']==most_liquid_contracts]
```

or perhaps do I need a merge? It seems less elegant and I'm also not sure.. I've tried:

```
# ATTEMPT 1
most_liquid_contracts.index = pd.to_datetime(most_liquid_contracts.index, unit='d')
df['days'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index.date, unit='d')
mlc = most_liquid_contracts.to_frame(name='delivery')
mlc['days'] = mlc.index.date
data = pd.merge(mlc, df, on=['delivery', 'days'], left_index=True)

# ATTEMPT 2
liquid = pd.merge(mlc, df, on='delivery', how='inner', left_index=True)
# this gets me closer (ie. retains granularity), but somehow seems to be an outer join? it includes the union but not the intersection. this should be a subset of df, but instead has about x50 the rows, at around 195B. df originally has 4B
```

But I can't seem to retain the minute-level granularity that I need in the original "df". Essentially, I just need the "df" for only the most liquid contracts (which comes from the most_liquid_contracts Series; eg. April 27th would only include "706"-labeled contracts, April 29th only "706"-labeled contracts). Then a second df for the exact opposite: a df for all other contracts (ie. *not* the most liquid).

UPDATE: for more information--
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky part is merging the two series/dataframes that have indexes with different datetime resolutions. Once you combine them intelligently, you can just filter normally.

```
# Make sure your series has a name
# Make sure the index is pure dates, not date 00:00:00
most_liquid_contracts.name = 'most'
most_liquid_conttracts.index = most_liquid_contracts.index.date

data = df
data['day'] = data.index.date
combined = data.join(most_liquid_contracts, on='day', how='left')
```

Now you can do something like

```
combined[combined.delivery == combined.most]
```

This will yield the rows in `data` (`df`) where `data.delivery` is equal to the value in `most_liquid_contracts` for that day.

Comment: I've tried using `combined = df.join(mlc, on='days', how='left')` but I got this error: `ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index([u'delivery', u'days'], dtype='object')`.. I've posted an image above in my original thread

Comment: Get rid of the `'days'` column in your `mlc` series since it is redundant with the index. Or, specify `right_suffix` and/or `left_suffix` in the join.

Comment: This worked! Thanks. I was definitely unclear on how to use 'join()' but that helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that I have understood you correctly, and that the most_liquid_contracts series is the series that contains the N largest deliveries for some integer N.  You want to filter df to include only days with delivery number high enough to make the list.  Therefore, you can simply remove everything in df that isn't larger than the minimum of most_liquid_contracts.

```
threshold = min(most_liquid_contracts)
filtered = df[df['delivery'] >= threshold]
```

Comment: Sorry perhaps I wasn't clear. I need only one delivery contract per day - the one that is listed in the series "most_liquid_contracts". The fact that the delivery contract is a number is confusing, it could well be "A", "B", etc. I just need a dataframe that, for each day, samples just the "contract name" listed in most_liquid_contracts, and then a second dataframe that is everything else. Does that clarify at all?

Comment: One more clarification because my comment above wasn't that clear. I need one dataframe that has the (1) datetime index, (2) the most liquid contract for that day, which comes from the most_liquid_contracts series, and (3) associated volume for that contract on that day. This is because I only want volume for the _most_ liquid contract of that particular day. So if a day has two contracts, that's not what I need. You can ignore the second part about "everything else" because I realized I can just find total volume and subtract out the most liquid contract's volume to find "everything else".

Comment: Check out wflynny's solution below.  It's better than what I would have come up with.